# How to pass argument from previous View to a Form?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

Im trying to pass the "test" argument from this View to a Form:

```
class ListCreateFormView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'armybuilder_list_create.html'
    model = List
    form_class = CreateListForm
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        self.test = Faction.objects.get(title="Blood Angels")
        return super().form_valid(form)
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('add_unit_to_list', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk, 'test': self.test.id})
```

To this View and Form:

```
class AddUnitsToListFormView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = SoldierToList
    form_class = SoldierToListForm
    template_name = 'armybuilder_add_unit_to_list.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        form.instance.list_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        return super().form_valid(form)

class SoldierToListForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # factions_obj = Faction.objects.get(pk=my_test)
        self.fields['soldier'].queryset = Soldier.objects.filter(factions=4)
    class Meta:
        model = SoldierToList
        fields = ('soldier',)
```

My urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('list/create', ListCreateFormView.as_view(), name='create_list'),
    path('list/own/<int:pk>/<int:test>/addunit', AddUnitsToListFormView.as_view(), name='add_unit_to_list'),
]
```

Im hardcoding the value 4 in my form but I would like to use the argument test that I defined in the previous View **ListCreateFormView**, can you please tell me how to do it ?

Thanks

Comment: Web programming 101: HTTP is a stateless protocol. If you want to share data between two requests, you have to either make the cient pass those data explicitely via the request (in the querystring, as part of your url path or as part of a POST request body), or use sessions (or any other shared storage - database etc).

Comment: I added my urls to my post

Comment: Well, you're already passing the desired value as part of your urlpattern, so you just have to grab it from the kwargs in AddUnitsToListFormView and pass it to the form's own kwargs (hint: pop it from the form's kwargs before calling `super().__init__()` else `ModelForm.__init__ might complain about not knowing this parameter). RE how to pass it to the form, you'll have to look at CreateView's (and it's various parents) doc - I almost never use class based views as they mostlly make things much more complicated than they have to ;-)

Comment: that was it, thanks :)